# On scroll progress bar move without using overflow css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, progress-bar, scrollbar

[image]I have a very interesting question.
Actually, everything works fine.

I have one div in which some events when I scroll over this div my progress bar which is placed at the top of the page move.

and I have also done when my cursor on scroll detect my div then my progress bar div show otherwise it remains hidden.

So Finally I want there is no overflow on my div but when I scroll window over this my progress bar move.

Here, Is my code please review it and help will be appreciated.

```js
$('#slide').scroll(function () {
 var scroll        = $(this).scrollTop();
 var scroll_height = $(this).get(0).scrollHeight;
 var height        = $(this).height();
 var percent       = scroll / (scroll_height - height) * 100;

 $("#progressbar").attr('value', percent);
  });

   $(window).scroll(function() {
  if(isOnScreen($("#slide"))){
   $("#progressbar").show();
   console.log("dikhgya");
  } else {
   $("#progressbar").hide();
   console.log("nhi");
     }
     
 });
 var para = document.createElement("Progress");
 para.setAttribute('id', 'progressbar');
 para.setAttribute('value', 0);
 para.setAttribute('max', 100);
 document.getElementById("slide").appendChild(para);
```

```css
progress {
       height: 6px;
     top: 46px;
     left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     /* bottom: 1326px; */
     position: fixed;
     margin-left: -1px;
     margin-top: -1px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div type="timeline" id="slide">
  <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article> Content</article>
  </section>
   <section>
    <header>Title two</header>
    <article> Content</article>
  </section>
   <section>
    <header>Title three</header>
    <article> Content</article>
  </section>
   <section>
    <header>Title four</header>
    <article> Content</article>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: help anyone is there?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is you want to scroll the page but not display scroll bar for this but rather a progress bar.

I have created a fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/8059/

```
<div id="timeline-wrapper" >
    <div type="timeline" id="slide">
      <section>
        <header>Title one</header>
        <article> Content</article>
     </section>
   </div>
</div>
```

In css you have to add properties *overflow:hidden* to *timeline-wrapper* and *overflow:auto* to *slide*. Then add *padding-right:16px* to *slide* where 16px is width of scrollbar in webkit based browsers.

```
#timeline-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 99%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 16px;
}
```

In this fiddle I have removed scroll bar and scrolling is portrayed by progress bar.
Hope this answers your question!!

Comment: thanks but you are not getting my point. think there is no scrollbar it detect my div then on div scroll and progress bar move this is my question

Comment: Do you want to detect **div** in DOM  and when user scrolls down from div , progress bar should move?

Comment: yes exaclty you can check my code. if possible please give me solution 2 din se pareshan hu i am indian.